# Controlling margins and icon for angulars mfb-menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am new to angularJs and web app devlopment. Just trying to understand floating buttons of angular and its properties (http://nobitagit.github.io/ng-material-floating-button/). This is the small `[plunkr][1]` (`http://plnkr.co/edit/4eFxqSg21U5ZR5H59rdK?p=preview`) for the same. I am trying to to modify the plunkr to acheive the mentioned.

1.Factors that adjust the buttons vertical dsitance

2.Methods to add custom PNG instead of "ion-ios-star"

For controlling the dstance i tried altering the margins for it never worked out and oor controlling icon i still have no clue.

Request some guidance

**Trail - 1 modifying mfb.css**

```
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }
  .mfb-component__list > li {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 1px;
    padding: 30px 0; //changed padding from 0 - 60 does not give any effect
    margin: -10px 0; 
   // (From 0 to 60*) Yes it had effect on distance between main menu and first child element.
//However, none of the other available give margin in the  class is giving effect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The vertical distance between each `<li>` element is handled by the following css selector. `.mfb-component__list > li` which means select all `<li>` elements that are children of the `.mfb-component__list` class. You can make changes to the padding and margin of that selector to change the vertical spacing between icons.
2. The glyph-icons built into the plunkr can be removed by swapping out the `.ion-ios_##` classes for your own custom glyphicon or css class. You could use background-image here to set a custom png. or you could even embed and image within the HTML.

Comment: I tried the first point mentioned.. Still i do not see any reflection over widget.